# Is a normal matrix with distinct singular values and real $M^*M$ necessarily symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose

1. $M\in{M_n}$ is normal
2. singular values  of $M$ are distinct
3. $M^*M$ is a real matrix

Is this true that  $M$ is symmetric?

Comment: Does symmetric mean "Hermitian" here? For example, is 
$$
\pmatrix{i\\&i}
$$
a "symmetric" matrix?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496900/if-b-is-normal-singular-values-of-b-are-distinct-bb-is-a-real-matrix

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Oh, several identical questions, must be time for the home exam in math at some university. Let's track the IPs.

Comment: @A.G. I believe that they are the same person unless they share the same bad language teacher (just guessing by the "is this true that" pattern).

Answer (score 1):

**A few hints:**

1. A normal matrix $M$ is unitarily diagonalizable: $M=UDU^*$ for some unitary $U$ and diagonal $D$.
2. $M^*M=U|D|^2U^*$ is the spectral decomposition of $M^*M$. The diagonal entries of $|D|$ are singular values of $M$.
3. If $M^*M$ is real and has distinct eigenvalues then, in the spectral decomposition $U|D|^2U^*$, the unitary matrix can be chosen in the form $U=V\Phi$, where $V$ is real orthogonal and $\Phi$ is a diagonal unitary matrix.

This gives $M=VDV^T$ because $\Phi D\Phi^*=D\Phi\Phi^*=D$ and hence $M$ is symmetric.